# How can I draw an internal arc in canvas, the same as the browser draws in html, for example, for div?

Tags: google-chrome, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to draw a rectangle border on a canvas for a rectangle with borders of different widths and a rounded corner. This drawing should look exactly like a div with the same parameters in the browser.

It is unclear to me what algorithm the inner arc should have (marked in blue in the screenshot). Is it drawn by bezier curves? If yes, then tell me its parameters.

If someone can throw off a link to the code, for example, of the chrome or mozilla browser, where you can see exactly how such arcs are drawn, I would be grateful.

An example in the browser can be viewed for example here:

```css
.rect {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 150px;
  border-top-color: black;
  border-right-width: 10px;
  border-right-color: green;
  border-top-right-radius: 220px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rect"></div>
```

[image]

I tried to select various parameters for the Bezier curve, but there are always small errors. I.e. the algorithm itself did not pick up. Similarly, I tried to draw a curve with an oval, but this is also very different from the html version.

I check the result by overlaying the html div over the canvas element.

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) and [mcve]. All relevant code needs to be in the question as text. We have [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) which replaces CodePen.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [the specs](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds/#corner-shaping) directly:

> The padding edge (inner border) radius is the outer border radius minus the corresponding border thickness. In the case where this results in a negative value, the inner radius is zero.

So in our case this gives the x-axis radius of our top-right quarter ellipse should be `220px` from the `border-radius` value minus the `10px` from the `border-right-width`, and the y-axis one should be `220px - 150px`.

To draw that in canvas, we can use the handy [`roundRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/roundRect) method, which does accept the same kind of parameters as `border-radius` and thus allows us to control each axis of every corners of the rounded rectangle.

```js
const ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.roundRect(0, 150, 602, 202, [0, {x: 210, y: 70}, 0, 0])
ctx.fill();
```

```css
.rect {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 150px;
  border-top-color: orange;
  border-right-width: 10px;
  border-right-color: green;
  border-top-right-radius: 220px;
  position: absolute; top: 30px;
}
canvas { position: absolute; top: 30px; }
canvas:hover { opacity: 0.5 }
```

```html
<div class="rect"></div>
<canvas width=800 height=600></canvas>
Move your mouse over to lower the canvas opacity
```

And if you want to stroke only that particular corner, then use the [`ctx.ellipse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/ellipse) method, using the same radii we calculated above:

```js
const ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
const radX = 210;
const radY = 70;
ctx.ellipse(602 - radX, 150 + radY, radX, radY, 0, -Math.PI / 2, 0);
ctx.stroke();
```

```css
.rect {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 150px;
  border-top-color: orange;
  border-right-width: 10px;
  border-right-color: green;
  border-top-right-radius: 220px;
  position: absolute; top: 30px;
}
canvas { position: absolute; top: 30px; }
canvas:hover { opacity: 0.5 }
```

```html
<div class="rect"></div>
<canvas width=800 height=600></canvas>
Move your mouse over to lower the canvas opacity
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
The problem meant that it is necessary to draw the arc itself (i.e. I draw the border itself, and not the inside of the rectangle).
But you gave me the right idea. As a result, I did it through arcTo.
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(startPoint.x, startPoint.y);  
ctx.scale(xRadius, yRadius);  
ctx.arcTo(0, -1, -1, -1, 1);  
ctx.restore();

Comment: @Николай please remember to edit your question as was asked in the comment below it, and also update it to clarify that you only want that particular corner to be drawn. And to do so, use `ctx.ellipse()` instead of that `scale()` hack, I'll update my answer shortly, but please edit your question.

Comment: I corrected the question.
`ctx.ellipse` is not suitable in my case, because, as I understand, it is not used as part of a drawn path (and I need to draw the path of the entire border along with the inner and outer arcs). Therefore, in my case, `cts.arcTo` gives a perfect match with the html border

Comment: `ellipse()` can be used as a part of a bigger path, that's actually the method we used to spec `roundRect()`, not sure where you got anything saying otherwise. `arcTo` isn't suitable to do the 2 axes scaling without a CTM hack, so `ellipse` is definitely what you need.